# Flex Justify Content isn't working both Vertical and Horizontal way

Tags: html, css, flexbox

`enter code here`My body height is 100%, Html height is 100%, root height 100%, and this section is 100%

> ```
> section{
>   max-width: 50%;
>   height: 100%;
>   display: flex;
>   flex-direction: column;
>   background-color: grey;
>   justify-items: center;
>   align-items: center;
> }
> ```

Inside this section, i put a `h1` and a `form`, and i limited it to 50px to test why isnt vertical aligning

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 1.6rem arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}

h1,
form {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

section{
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: grey;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id=root>
  <section>
    <h1>Lista Tarefas</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type=" submit ">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

But, if i remove the `flex-direction: column;` , there is vertical alignment but not the horizontal alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's `justify-content`, *not*  `justify-items`as you wrote.

And in your particular example, the input field and the words won't fit into 50x50px, so that's kind of unrealistic. Use a realistic size (width) and maybe also add `text-align: center;` if you want to center the text and button within those elements:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 1.6rem arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}

h1,
form {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

section{
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: grey;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id=root>
  <section>
    <h1>Lista Tarefas</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type=" submit ">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: i wanna kill myself. It was this damn "justify-items" that was killing me LOL. the VsCode just gave me the complement and i accepted. Thank you very much